# How do I set an object as the value in Redis Cache using Mock XUnit Testing?

Tags: c#, .net, redis, xunit, stackexchange.redis

I am trying to write some unit tests for testing my redis cache methods. Does anyone know the proper way to set this up using Mocks?

I have this object that I want to store in the Mock Redis Cache db

```
Dog pet = new Dog {
    name = "Jon"
    id = "1234"
}
```

I am creating a mock of the Redis Cache DB as shown below. CacheAccessor is my own class for setting/getting data from Redis.

```
var fakeDB = new Mock<IDatabase>();
var redisCacheMethods = new CacheAccessor(fakeDB.Object);
```

And I want to try and set that pet object in redis cache using the mock DB. This is what I have so far

```
Dog pet = new Dog {
    name = "Jon"
    id = "1234"
}

var fakeDB = new Mock<IDatabase>();
var redisCacheMethods = new CacheAccessor(fakeDB.Object);

fakeDB.Setup(t => t.StringGetAsync(It.IsAny<RedisKey>(), It.IsAny<CommandFlags>())).Returns(Task.Run<RedisValue>(() =>
            {
                return pet.ToString(); // sets the value in Redis
            }));
var response = await cacheAccessor.GetAsync(key); // this is supposed to retrieve that pet object but it throws some parsing error.
```

And in my CacheAccessor, when I retrieve the value, it just shows up as the model name like **{AppServices.Models.Dog}** whereas it should show up as the Dog object with the attributes inside like with name and id. I believe it is something with the pet.ToString() which doesn't store the object properly in Redis Cache?

CacheAccessor that contains the GetAsync method that gets the value stored in Redis

```
public async Task<Pet> GetAsync(string key, Type petType= null)
    {
// Returns {AppServices.Models.Dog} instead of the actual pet object I initially stored
      var res = await this.cacheDatabase.StringGetAsync(key).ConfigureAwait(false); // returns a Stack.Exchange.RedisValue

      var deserializedResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseText, entityType);
      return deserializedResponse != null ? (pet)deserializedResponse : null;
        }
```

Comment: `pet.ToString()` is not the Dog object. Can you share the relevant code of `GetAsync` method?

Comment: @chetan added it to the original post

Comment: StringGetAsync returns json string from the redis which then deserialized into class object. So you need to setup method to return the json of dog object instead of pet.ToString()

Comment: I think that worked! I just serialized pet instead of doing pet.ToString(). Thank you.